# Do we know if the Human Torch needs to breathe oxygen?

Tags: marvel, fantastic-four

When his powers are active and he's fully on fire, does the Human Torch need to breathe oxygen to survive?

You'd imagine the fire he's generating would consume any oxygen before it made it past his lips *(which are on fire)*.

Has this ever been addressed in canon anywhere, even in a passing comment in recognition of it?

Comment: I want to say that one of the early comics where Dr. Doom captured the team had him trapping Johnny in an airtight cell such that the flames died out, then Johnny went unconscious. IIRC, it was one of the ones where Sue saves everyone.

Comment: I know in that horrible Fantastic Four movie with the Silver Surfer, when the Surfer is fighting Johnny, the Surfer drags him up to a point in or above our atmosphere where the oxygen is very thin. His flames die out and he blacks out

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13727/how-much-air-does-johnny-burn

Comment: Maybe he gets oxygen through the flames, rather than his lungs, when on?  At least, that would make sense if he passes out at not having oxygen to flame, like not having it to breathe, as the previous comments mention.

Answer (score 1):

[Marvel openly says](http://marvel.com/universe/Human_Torch_(Johnny_Storm)#New_Flames) that Johhny covers his body with flames when he "flames on." He doesn't become a giant ball of flame. His body is still under the fire.

*If he became fire itself, it would be fair to say that the fire's consumption of oxygen is equivalent to his own; for him burning oxygen equates to breathing.*

Since he is still alive when he flames on, he needs to breahte in order to stay conscious. There are multiple incidents (in movies) of him losing conscious when he couldn't breathe and him losing his flames.

In comics, there was one moment when he could not flame on because of his inner doubts, and is a metaphor for his wasted potential. But this had nothing to do with breathing.

[image]

And in "THE FALL OF THE FANTASTIC FOUR" PART 4, Johnny loses his powers but I haven't read the issue so I'm avoiding spoilers. I highly doubt it is oxygen-related.

Human Tourch needs to breathe. But the kind of oxygen consumption you are referring does not entirely work when you consider how much he breathes at a time and how much his lips could burn.

Comment: Well I asked the question under the assumption he was covered in fire, not actually transformed into a human shaped flame.

Comment: @InguShama Above answers the same thing.